# Identifying the parents of Moritz Martin Bernhardt born 1827 Treptow Prussia

Tags: birth-records, jewish, prussia

Moritz Martin Bernhardt is my great-grand father.

I was able to learn his age and place of birth (1827 Treptow, Prussia) from his application for US Citizenship.

I found his date and place of death (1862 Fredericksburg, Texas) in the pioneer church book in Fredericksburg, Texas.

His life and family in Prussia, however,  is still unknown and I would like to identify his parents and gain more precise information about his birth.

Comment: I've edited your question based on the more detailed information you've provided and focussed it on finding more details of his birth. If you want a different focus, you can use the Edit button under the question to modify it.

Answer (score 3):

Have you sought out his tombstone?  Jewish tombstones when inscribed in Hebrew will often give the father's first name as in Moritz (possibly Moshe in Hebrew) son of the honorable ______.